# Image Edge Detection in C++

Tags: c++, image, matlab, edge-detection

I am trying to find a way to determine the correctness of edge detection. I want it to have little markers showing where the program determines the edges to be with something like x's or dots or lines. I am looking for something that does this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Corner.png

Comment: Don't mix edge detection with corner detection  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection

Comment: If you want corner(feature) detection go for SIFT. There is a file for matlab if you search google. If you want edge detectio go for canny, already built in matlab

Answer (score 4):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) has an [edge detector](http://silveiraneto.net/2009/12/04/opencv-edge-detection/) and is usable in C++. As it happens the image you linked to is used in the article describing (one of) the built in algorithms.

Comment: yeah but does it have markers as to where the program determines where the edge is

Comment: The result of the Edge Detector will be an image (mostly white) with all the detected edges. You can overlap this with the original image and then paint red all the overlapping pixels. You should end up with something similar to what you are expecting.

Comment: You might also want to look at some of the other feature detectors that OpenCV implements ( http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/feature_detection.html )

Answer (score 2):

The image you link to ins't edge detection.

Edge detection is normally just finding abrubt brightness changes in a greyscale image - you do this with differention - eg. Sobel operator.

Specifically finding corners is either done with SIFT or something like Laplacian of Gaussians

Comment: yeah i know. it was just an example of what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

That image is not result of edge detection operations! It's [**corner detection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection). They have entirely different purposes:

> Corner detection is an approach used
>   within computer vision systems to
>   extract certain kinds of features and
>   infer the contents of an image. Corner
>   detection is frequently used in motion
>   detection, image matching, tracking,
>   image mosaicing, panorama stitching,
>   3D modelling and object recognition.
>   Corner detection overlaps with the
>   topic of interest point detection.

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) has [corner detection](http://www.aishack.in/2010/05/corner-detection-in-opencv/) algorithms. The latest link includes a [source code example](http://www.aishack.in/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/src_GoodFeaturesToTrack.zip) for VS 2008. You can also [check this link](http://www.moosechips.com/2008/08/opencv-corner-detection-using-cvgoodfeaturestotrack/) for another example. Google can provide much more.